# Multiple homepage layouts as selected by user from theme options

Tags: wp-query, themes, theme-options

I am working on a theme which will enable users to select multiple layouts from the theme options panel.

What I did so far is to create multiple theme files, depending on each theme, put it in a directory and let the user select an option from the themes panel. Then relate the option and include it in `front-page.php`. All is working fine, except for a custom post type: *portfolio*.

It gave me the results I needed using this loop :

```
global $wp_query;

$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('post_type=portfolio&paged='.$paged);
if ($wp_query->have_posts()) : while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();  ?>
```

It did as required, output the posts, but it made the navigation disappear and pagination broke as well. Pagination is giving a 404 on page 2 (it is considering this as the main query maybe...)

So for that I used this function:

```
function alter_query_portfolio($qry) {
   if ( ! is_main_query() ) {
       if ( 'portfolio' == $qry->get( 'post-type' ) ) {     
           $qry->set('post_type','portfolio');
       }     
    }
}   

add_action('pre_get_posts','alter_query_portfolio');
```

It didn't fixed it. What should I do about it?

Comment: Check this [search results](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22custom+post+type%22+pagination+wp_query).

Comment: Where is `$paged` being set? If it's undefined, that would cause a PHP error (which could cause the navigation to disappear) and would certainly prevent proper pagination. Make sure you have `WP_DEBUG` defined as `true` while you've doing development.

Comment: i defined paged in start as well, but it didn't fixed. i need a solution mainly where i can get users to use any layout of their choice, its not just pagination but also if portfolio layout is switched on, general posts permalinks stops working , vice versa...